# SSO logout using ITfoxtec Saml2 issue

Tags: c#, .net-4.7.2, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am new to implementing SAML2.  I have had good success with using the [ITfoxtec framework](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebApp). I am able to connect to the IDP, login, and return back to my AssertionConsumerService successfully.  The app that this is being integrated into is using .NET 4.7.2 framework. I'm referencing the ITfoxtec github solution in this ticket as I'm using methods directly from it in my app.

The issue comes when logging out. I receive this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Missing Claim Type: http://schemas.itfoxtec.com/ws/2014/02/identity/claims/saml2nameid'
```

I'm currently using this [method](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebApp/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L62) to logout.  The error shown above corresponds to this section of code:

```
var logoutRequest = new Saml2LogoutRequest(config, ClaimsPrincipal.Current).DeleteSession();
```

So my question is, what am I missing in terms of setting this up correctly?  I'm using this to [login](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebApp/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L26) and this for the [AssertionConsumerService](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebApp/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L43).  Do I need to make changes to my login [bindings](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebApp/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L31)?  Its currently all commented out. Where does the claim saml2nameid get assigned?

Answer (score 0):

The IdP is required to issue a NameID and a session index to [enable logout](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Request/Saml2LogoutRequest.cs#L50), this is a required in the SAML 2.0 standard. The [NameID is saved](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Tokens/Saml2ResponseSecurityTokenHandler.cs#L90) in the `http://schemas.itfoxtec.com/ws/2014/02/identity/claims/saml2nameid` claim.

Comment: Turns out I had to manually add the NameID, as they were sending a value of NameIdentifier...